# Checking Postal Codes with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to build a form which checks if an entered zip code matches a zip code in a predefined array. I don't use a DB, it's all very basic and hardcoded, but should be sufficient in this case.

The problem is that only the first zip-code in the array ('*83512*') works. If i am entering the second one ('*83533*') the code spits out "*no success*".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:alert('success.');" id="checkplz">
    <label for="plz">ZIP:</label>
    <input type="text" name="plz" id="plz" />
    <button id="submit" >Check!</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = ['83512','83533'];
    $("#checkplz").submit(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if ($("#plz").val() == list[i]) {
                $("#output").append("<strong class='success'>success!</strong>").show();
                return true;
            }
            $("#output").text("no success!").show().fadeOut(10000);
                return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the logic of your loop. The loop will only run one time, because the loop will always return after the first iteration (true if it finds the first element in the list array, false for everything else), rather than continuing through all iterations. So, what is happening for the second element is that the loop is running, determining that the first element was not found and returning false and never even processing the second element.

A better way to do this would be to loop the list array until you find a matching element, and keep track of wether an match was found or not. This will make sure we don't drop out of the loop until we've processed all elements of the array (or found a match, in which case we can stop the loop to save on processing).

See below (http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/Kws7A/) for some example code with a few comments about what is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = ['83512','83533'];
    $("#checkplz").submit(function() {
        var matched = false; // Set up variable to track if we find a match
        $(list).each(function() {
            // Inside the jQuery 'each' method, 'this' equals the current item in the iteration.
            if(this == $("#plz").val()) {
                matched = true; // set the 'matched' variable to true
                $("#output").append("<strong class='success'>success!</strong>").show();
                return; // Since we found a match, we can stop processing the array
            }
        });
        // Outside of the loop, only display no success if we didn't find any matches.
        if (!matched) {
            $("#output").text("no success!").show().fadeOut(10000);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic in your loop is off.  See below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = ['83512','83533'];
    $("#checkplz").submit(function() {
        var match = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if ($("#plz").val() == list[i]) {
                         $("#output").append("<strong class='success'>success!</strong>").show();
                return true;   
            }

        }

        $("#output").text("no success!").show().fadeOut(10000);
                return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false outside the loop, so it will only happen once all values are checked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = ['83512','83533'];
    $("#checkplz").submit(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if ($("#plz").val() == list[i]) {
                $("#output").append("<strong class='success'>success!</strong>").show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        $("#output").text("no success!").show().fadeOut(10000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.inArray()

```
var list = ['83512','83533'];
if($.inArray('83533', list) > -1){
    // found
}
```

Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/